# I don't understand why I am getting an index out of bound exception?

Tags: java, indexoutofboundsexception

This is previous year exam question that has errors, but I can't seem to understand why? I keep on getting this error:

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.StringIndexOutOfBoundsException: String index out of range: 21

```
public class SwimmingPool{ 

  public static void countSpaces(String s){
    int count = 0;

    for(int i = 0; i <= s.length(); i++){
      if(s.charAt(i) == ' '){
        count++;
      }
    }
    System.out.println("Percent of spaces is" + count /
    s.length());
  }

  public static void main (String[] args){

    String s = "lefhg aljdfgh liauh h";
    countSpaces(s);
  }      
}
```

Comment: `i <= s.length()`... really, you should **at least** debug your code before posting a question.

Answer (score 4):

```
for(int i = 0; i <= s.length(); i++){
```

should be (Observe that it is just less than symbol, NOT less than equal):

```
for(int i = 0; i < s.length(); i++){
```

EDIT:

`String` index starts from ZERO and go up to `String length() -1`. If you use `<=s.length()`, you will look one index past the end of the string (when = condition check happens).

Comment: I think it'd be useful to explain why `s.length()` is out of bounds.  Otherwise, you're giving an answer sans explanation.

Comment: That's not quite right in the explanation.  A String with `length()` of 10 has 10 characters, indexed 0 through 9.  The *last index* is always `length() - 1`

Comment: @IanMcLaird: Yes I mean index, updated. Feel free to update (I am not native English speaker)

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is here:

```
for(int i = 0; i <= s.length(); i++)
```

It should be:

```
for(int i = 0; i < s.length(); i++) //note that it is LESS THAN
```

String indices are 0-based in Java and run from `0` to `string.length() - 1`. So you're trying to access a character at location `string.length()`, which does not exist. This is why you're getting the exception.

Answer (score 0):

`String` internally use an array and array indexes valid range is from `0` to `length-1` . Your code within the `for` loop will try to access the `array[length]` element, which will throw `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundException`.

So change your for loop condition to iterate only till the length-1 index(last element).

```
for(int i = 0; i <= s.length(); i++)
```

should be

```
for(int i = 0; i < s.length(); i++)
```

Comment: It's not an array; it's a `String`. :)

Answer (score 0):

You need to make the following 2 changes:

1 
   Change

```
 for(int i = 0; i <= s.length(); i++){
```

To

```
 for(int i = 0; i < s.length(); i++){
```

2  `count / s.length()` need to be changed. If you do so, it will be zero in your example.

Use `100.0 *count / s.length()` for instead, like

```
System.out.printf("Percent of spaces is " + 100.0 *count / s.length());
```

Output in Console:

```
Percent of spaces is 14.285714285714286
```

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, we can access upto "s.length-1" and not till "s.length" because of whic we are getting the exception.
Secondly, to get the percentage in terms of "count /s.length() " would be difficult as both are of int datatype, and the result is coming in decimal which is getting rounded off and appearing as 0. If we declare count as double, then we can get the exact percentage.

public static void countSpaces(String s){
        double count = 0.0;

```
    for(int i = 0; i < s.length(); i++){
      if(s.charAt(i) == ' '){
        count++;
      }
    }
    System.out.println("Percent of spaces is" + count /
    s.length());
  }

  public static void main (String[] args){

    String s = "lefhg aljdfgh liauh h";
    countSpaces(s);
  }
```